# How does the Ubuntu boot process work?

Tags: boot, upstart, init, init.d

I have read many articles about the Linux boot process. As I understand the Linux boot process is something like this :

```
BIOS (UEFI) → MBR → grub → Kernel → init
```

What I really don't understand what the `etc/sbin/init` starts and what the relation between the Ubuntu upstart daemon, `/etc/init.d` and run levels is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 resources that will help you understand the boot process better:

1. `bootchart`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bootchart
   sudo reboot
   ```

   Now every time a chart like [this one](http://www.bootchart.org/images/bootchart.png) will be created in `/var/log/bootchart/` every time you reboot.  You can learn a lot by looking at a boot chart of a system you know intimately: yours! **;-)**
2. IBM's manual [Inside the Linux Boot Process](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/)